# Electron player video quality problem

Tags: video, amazon, quality

I recently downloaded electronplayer to watch amazon prime and disney+ but it seems to me that their videos are not running in HD the video quality is very low like 360p so I goto chrome and play amazon prime via chrome but the results are the same I don't know why the quality is low but in my other machines which use windows there quality is great. Is there a way to watch in HD.